# Развернуть список 4-х уровневый список в Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, bootstrap

Всем привет, помогите пожалуйста реализовать данный скрипт. Есть 4 уровненный список через цикл в виде Laravel. Необходимо чтобы при клике открывался список с последующей категории. Пример как необходимо Авито

[image: Пример]

Песочница

Comment: Прикрепил песочницу

https://jsfiddle.net/usdbuy/4dL8rfkc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не стал разбирать ваш код, но вот набросал [пример](https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=0010)

```js
let lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');

lis.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (el.children.length > 0) {
      el.children[0].style.display = el.children[0].style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
  })
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li>ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="parent">
    уровень1 - 1 --- 4 уровня
    <ul style="display: none">
      <li class="parent">
        подпункт 1 --- 4 уровня
        <ul style="display: none">
          <li>подпункт 1</li>
          <li>подпункт 2 --- 4 уровня
            <ul style="display: none">
              <li>подпункт 1</li>
              <li>подпункт 2</li>
              <li>подпункт 3</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>подпункт 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="parent">
        подпункт 2
        <ul style="display: none">
          <li>подпункт 1</li>
          <li>подпункт 2</li>
          <li>подпункт 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="parent">
        подпункт 3
        <ul style="display: none">
          <li>подпункт 1</li>
          <li>подпункт 2</li>
          <li>подпункт 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent">
    уровень1 - 2
    <ul style="display: none">
      <li class="parent">
        подпункт 1
        <ul style="display: none">
          <li>подпункт 1</li>
          <li>подпункт 2</li>
          <li>подпункт 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="parent">
        подпункт 2
        <ul style="display: none">
          <li>подпункт 1</li>
          <li>подпункт 2</li>
          <li>подпункт 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="parent">
        подпункт 3
        <ul style="display: none">
          <li>подпункт 1</li>
          <li>подпункт 2</li>
          <li>подпункт 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent">
    уровень1 - 3
    <ul style="display: none">
      <li class="parent">
        подпункт 1
        <ul style="display: none">
          <li>подпункт 1</li>
          <li>подпункт 2</li>
          <li>подпункт 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="parent">
        подпункт 2
        <ul style="display: none">
          <li>подпункт 1</li>
          <li>подпункт 2</li>
          <li>подпункт 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="parent">
        подпункт 3
        <ul style="display: none">
          <li>подпункт 1</li>
          <li>подпункт 2</li>
          <li>подпункт 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Код №2 с проверкой на ul

```js
let lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');

lis.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    let children = el.children;
    for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
     if(children[i].nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'ul'){
      children[i].style.display = children[i].style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
      }
    };
   
  })
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li>ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
  <li class="parent">
    <a href="#">уровень1 - 2</a>
    <ul style="display: none">
      <li class="parent">
       <a href="#">подпункт 1</a>
        <ul style="display: none">
          <li><a href="#">подпункт 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">подпункт 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">подпункт 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="parent">
        <a href="#">подпункт 2</a>
        <ul style="display: none">
          <li><a href="#">подпункт 1</a></li>
              <li class="parent">
             <a href="#">подподпункт 1</a>
            <ul style="display: none">
              <li><a href="#">подпункт 1</a></li>

              <li><a href="#">подпункт 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">подпункт 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">подпункт 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">подпункт 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="parent">
        <a href="#">подпункт 3</a>
        <ul style="display: none">
          <li><a href="#">подпункт 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">подпункт 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">подпункт 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent">
    <a href="#">уровень1 - 3</a>
    <ul style="display: none">
      <li class="parent">
        <a href="#">подпункт 1
        <ul style="display: none">
          <li><a href="#">подпункт 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">подпункт 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">подпункт 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="parent">
        подпункт 2
        <ul style="display: none">
          <li><a href="#">подпункт 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">подпункт 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">подпункт 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="parent">
        <a href="#">подпункт 3
        <ul style="display: none">
          <li><a href="#">подпункт 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">подпункт 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">подпункт 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо! то что нужно только подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы  последние подпункты оборачивались в тег <a></a>?

Comment: обернуть их в a )

Comment: у меня просто через цикл и когда первый оборачивается в тег а он не проходит к следующим подпунктам

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/usdbuy/ymgnktv0/7/

Comment: непонятно что вы имеете в виду, проверяйте наличие подпунктов и от этого формируйте линки, https://jsfiddle.net/jm34p8wL/

Comment: у меня получается есть цикл который выводит категории http://joxi.ru/BA0QngkHMjOKxr      Я добавил ваш код все ок, но все ок когда без тега а. Сейчас когда я добавил тег а в цикл при клике на первую категорию чтобы пройти дальше Категории теряются и срабаотывает переход по ссылке. Мне необходимо чтобы тег a срабатывал у последних категории. Продублировал проблему в песочницу https://jsfiddle.net/usdbuy/ymgnktv0/10/

Comment: Так тег a для этого и есть чтобы делать переход на другую страницу. Или вы хотите его перехватить? На авито тоже переходы, у них есть дополнительный `i` по нему список открывается

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста что сделать чтобы при клике в конечной категории элемент не пропадал короткое видео с проблемой https://yadi.sk/d/RZKDIAfxP3Id9Q

Comment: Кинул второй код, с проверкой на ul

Comment: Спасибо! то что нужно!